# What is FireFox's Device Manager used for?

Tags: firefox, pki

In FireFox, there is a Device Manager (Options->Advanced->Certificates->Security Devices) that allows you to import middle-ware for cryptographic tokens (as far as  can tell).

Can someone tell me what does FireFox do with these?

From what I have seen online, my guess is that it allows the automatic authentication of the user, when he navigates to a web page. Is that right?

But can it be used for anything else?

For example, is there a way to sign some data with JavaScript, using an imported middle-ware and a cryptographic token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use for these is using a smart card to authenticate to a website. This technology employs [mutual SSL authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication) where a user is authenticated by using a certificate. Usually you only have one-sided SSL authentication, where the server tries to authenticate that it really is who it says it is (normal SSL, EV, etc.), but this can also be done from the client side, resulting in much stronger authentication.

The smart card is used to store the private key of the certificate on the smart card, thereby making it much more difficult for the private key to be duplicated. Also some smartcards offer support for PIN numbers when trying to use the stored private key, resulting in two-factor authentication (something you have, the smart card, and something you know, the PIN number).

Comment: But do you know if one could also use this for signing data via some JavaScript API? I have seen JavaScript code used for loading the middle-ware (https://github.com/open-eid/firefox-pkcs11-loader/blob/master/chrome/content/pkcs11-loader.js) but not for using it. Perhaps it is meant to be used only internally by FireFox...

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I don't think so. I think this functionality can only be used to set up secure HTTP links and stuff. There are some ideas on the internet to use a smart card reader from a [Java applet](https://www.google.nl/search?q=firefox+javascript+smartcard+reader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BMSFVKahD4b3Uv2xgOgP#q=+javascript+smartcard+reader), but that's it.